# Pollution of the global namespace and onclick functions

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose the code

```js
//(function() {
  function addItem() {
    alert("item added!");
  }
//})();
```

```html
<button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
```

if I will take care of not polluting the global namespace, and will uncomment the commented code, my functionality will be broken...

What is the usual workaround for this kind of issues, keeping the html inline "on..." event handlers?

---

**PS.** As a note for begginner readers:

The experienced developers may advice to avoid inline `onclick` attributes. Among many reasons not to use them:

- tight coupling between presentation and behavior;
- code (usually) runs in the global scope;
- makes testing and debugging difficult;
- defies progressive enhancement;
- quickly becomes hard to maintain;
- also it will unbind any previously assigned click handlers which might be an unwanted side effect;

Comment: Instead of inline `onclick` event, use event binding through ___JS___.

Comment: I want my onclick

Comment: If you don't want to use the global namespace you can create your own and have `onclick="Whatever.You.Want.addItem()"`. In the long term, though, keeping JavaScript separated from HTML as Rayon suggests really pays off.

Comment: The usual workaround is not to keep HTML `onclick` attributes. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @melpomene, added a PS to explain this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) here:

```js
var myGlobalClosure = (function(){
     var myPrivateVariable = "item added from inside closure!";
     function addItem() {
        alert(myPrivateVariable);
     }
    
    return {addItem:addItem};
})();

//if I have variable collisions they don't affect my closed over code.
//so this illustrates one of the big advantages of this pattern
var myPrivateVariable = "this is in the global scope and won't do anything";
```

```html
<button onclick="myGlobalClosure.addItem()">add item</button>
```

The above closure is an example of the [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). This is a common JS structural design pattern.

Ultimately something needs to be in the global scope or else you can't reference it.The idea here is to organise your global objects so that they have structure. This will also prevent collisions on standard function/object names, like `click`, etc.

This is how most libraries structure their code, for example `jQuery`/`$` is a closure that closes over the jQuery functions and objects.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inline events, use event binding through ***JS*** using [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
(function() {
  var add_btn = document.getElementById('add_btn');

  function addItem() {
    alert("item added!");
  }
  add_btn.addEventListener('click', addItem);
})();
```

```html
<button id="add_btn">add item</button>
```

Comment: the OP question asked the workaround for and with "onlick"

Comment: is does not keep the "onlick", I want my onclick

Comment: @Serge - Click handler is still present but binding is done through JS. IMO it is better approach rather than having inline event binding.

Comment: I could agree that is the better approach, but actually the question is about global pollution **with** inline event handlers... thanks ;)

Comment: @Serge When a question involves a hard-coded limitation it's always good to know the brackground of it. Otherwise you may end up answering the "Best shoe to drive a nail" kind of question :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I agree, but the solution with JS binding I know, I just wondered if there are other ways... and if you read the HTML, is more readable for me, to know what an element does....

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep an inline `onclick` attribute, the other solution is to put the whole event handler code there:

```html
<button onclick="
void function () {
    function addItem() {
        alert('item added');
    }
    addItem();
}()
">add item</button>
```

---

You could also store the function in the button element itself, then look it up in the `onclick` handler:

```js
document.getElementById('add_butt').addItem = function () {
    alert("item added");
};
```

```html
<button id="add_butt" onclick="this.addItem()">add item</button>
```